# How can I access an upstream object, later down stream in RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java2

Let's say I have this Observable situation:

```java
public void main() {
    Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            .flatMap(id -> getEvenOdd(id))
            .map(string -> {
                // I now want to join string 
                // AND the last emitted ID integer
                return null;
            });
}
    
private Observable<String> getEvenOdd(Integer id) {
    if (id % 2 == 0) {
        return Observable.just("even");
    } else {
        return Observable.just("odd");
    }
}
```

The `flatmap` has transformed Integer into String. How can I now get access to the Integer inside `map`?

I know that I could add a `doOnNext` and cache the Integer:

```java
private Integer intCache; 
    
public void main() {
    Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            .doOnNext(integer -> intCache = integer)
            .flatMap(id -> getEvenOdd(id))
            .map(string -> {
                return intCache.toString() + " " + string;
            });
```

But this seems a little hacky and expands the scope of the Integer beyond my observable chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specialized `flatMap` for this use-case:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)

The second parameter combines the results from the flatmap with the item that caused them to be emitted.

So the updated example is

```
public void main() {
    Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            .flatMap(id -> getEvenOdd(id),
                    (BiFunction<Integer, String, String>) (integer, string) -> { // LOOK HERE
                        return string + Integer.toString(integer);
                    })
            .map(joinedStringAndInt -> {
                ... use joinedStringAndInt
            });
}
```

Where the third type in the BiFunction is the type of the combined value. Here I just chose to combined the String and Integer into another String

As a sidenote, the `doOnNext` solution is hacky and unsafe if you consider there can be multiple instances of the same Observable accessing the `intCache` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just to use nesting. You can have both the last observable emission and your value from parameter in a nested structure:

```
public void main() {
    Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
        .flatMap(id -> getEvenOdd(id)
            .map(string -> joinStringAndInt(string, id)))
        .map(joinedStringAndInt -> {
          // do your stuff here
          return something;
        });
}

private String joinStringAndInt(String string, Integer number) {
    return number.toString() + " " + string;
}

private Observable<String> getEvenOdd(Integer id) {
    if (id % 2 == 0) {
      return Observable.just("even");
    } else {
      return Observable.just("odd");
    }
}
```